# Why is there a delay in my electron app's mysql connection queries?

Tags: mysql, electron, node-mysql

Whenever I load the electron app, it performs the queries right away on some occasions, but on other times it has a delay. The whole html page, on the other hand, loads without delay.

I tested it out with only a single query and I put console.time() right before the query and console.timeEnd() after it. This always resulted in about 10 seconds (+ ~20ms). Putting the console.time() inside the query, however, resulted in about 20ms. I think this means the query itself takes 20ms but it takes time before it can make the query.

I have no idea where the 10 second delay is coming from or how to get rid of it. I'm currently on a Windows 10 machine connected to a local mysql database. With the same code, I don't have any problems running on my mac (when another local mysql database is installed there).

I suspect it has something to do with the default mysql connectTimeout (10s). Setting it to 1s (1000ms) essentially does the same thing but reduces the 10s delay to 1s. Now setting it to 0s, as one probably would seeing this pattern, either executes the query instantly or does not perform it at all. And this is one of the dangers I think of setting a low timeout especially when I end up with more intensive queries in the future.

Help and suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

edit: the first instance of loading the app performs queries just fine, but after a refresh or two the problem occurs.

edit2: minimal code to reproduce

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>foo bar</p>
    </body>
    <script>
        let mysql = require('mysql');
        let connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host    : 'localhost',
            user    : 'root',
            password: 'foo',
            database: 'bar'
        });

        let $sql = `SELECT Foo FROM bar;`;

        console.time();
        connection.query($sql, function (error, results, fields){
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log(results)
            console.timeEnd();
        });

    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you creating a lot of connections? What does `SHOW PROCESSLIST` say? You might be flooding the available connections, which by default is only 100, and other connections get refused.

Comment: @tadman here are screenshots of my process list: [link](https://imgur.com/a/O9Ygp3W). The query itself is just selecting all the values of a 12x7 table. Nothing too extreme. If I sent the wrong thing please do tell me.

Comment: Another possibility is DNS resolution, though that usually fails consistently. Do other processes have the same trouble connecting in that window? Can you make like 60 concurrent connections?

Comment: In my original file where there is more than one query, all the queries load at the same time (after the 10s delay that is). I tried opening the app 60 times and they all do load. However, I just realized that during the first instance I open the app, the queries are executed right away. But it is with any succeeding refreshes that the delays occur. I should have made this clear earlier sorry :// (just edited now) Does this make a difference?

Comment: Do you have a minimal amount of code that reproduces this problem?

Comment: @tadman see above edit

Comment: I figured since electron is designed to be a single page app, I might as well just combine everything into one html page to avoid refreshing. This at least avoids the problem. Thank you anyway @tadman for trying  :))

Comment: I'm not sure putting this in the "page" is the best plan. I haven't done much Electron, but isn't there a better way to specify this? I'd expect to see `import db from 'DB'` or something where that could persist between loads.